# Update key in hashmap retruns null while calling get method

Tags: java, hashmap

```
class Employee {
    private int employeeID;
    private String fName;

    public int getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    public void setEmployeeID(int employeeID) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.getEmployeeID(), this.getfName());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this.getEmployeeID() == ((Employee) obj).getEmployeeID();
    }
}

public class HashValueExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        e1.setEmployeeID(1);
        e1.setfName("Krutik Jayswal");
        
        Employee e2 = new Employee();
        e2.setEmployeeID(2);
        e2.setfName("Krutik");
        
        Map<Employee,String> map=new  HashMap<>();
        map.put(e1, "val1");
        map.put(e1, "val2");
        
        e1.setfName("updating values");
        
        //How to design a pojo in such a way so that below will not give null value?and if we update pojo is it ideal design solution?
        System.out.println(map.get(e1));

    }
}
```

How to design a pojo in such a way so that below will not give null value?and if we update pojo is it ideal design solution?

System.out.println(map.get(e1));

Answer (score 0):

Your `Map` keys should be immutable to avoid these kind of behaviours because a `Map#get` should be consistent and remain consistent.

So the only way to design your "POJO" would be to make immutable

```java
static class Employee {
    private final int employeeID;
    private final String fName;

    public Employee(int employeeID, String fName) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public int getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.getEmployeeID(), this.getfName());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this.getEmployeeID() == ((Employee) obj).getEmployeeID();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if we don't have control on pojo?

Comment: Then you should not use it as a key for your `Map`

Comment: @KrutikJayswal Then use `employeeId` as the key.